# Min and Max values for EditorFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying this code to set minimum and maximum on my `EditorFor`:

```
<label id="LbStartYear" style="width: 200px">From Date: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedYearBegin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @min = "0", @max = "20" } })</label>
```

But no success. Minimum and Maximum are never set. I tried removing the quotation from `0` and `20`, also tried with and without the `@`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Simply use `Range` DataAnnotation attribute on your model property. By using this attribute you can restrict user to enter any other number which doesn't fall in the range.

Import following namespaces -

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
```

And then decorate your property with `Range` attribute -

```
[Range(0,20)]
public int SelectedYearBegin { get; set; }
```

For more information on Range Attribute - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.rangeattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

You can get client side validation by enabling it in Web.config -

```
 <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
 <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

Make sure you link JQuery unobtrusive and validate JS files.

Alternatively if you still want to set `min` and `max` for `EditorFor`, then you need to get MVC 5.1 or higher. Below code works for MVC 5.1 and higher.

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SelectedYearBegin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @min = "0", @max = "20" } })
```

If you do not want to go for MVC 5.1 and higher, then simply use `TextBoxFor` -

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SelectedYearBegin, new { type = "number", min = 0, max = 100 })
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer better.

Comment: @AlexandreSeverino I updated my answer with details.

Comment: How do I "Make sure you link JQuery unobtrusive and validate JS files."?

Comment: I think modifying the web.config is not necessary, there is a helper `Html.EnableClientValidation(true);`