# How to get Min and Max values to TextBoxFor in .cshtml

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

Hello guys I'm new to MVC .net entity framework 4.5.

0 - $49000 Silver
$50000 - 99000 Gold
Greater than $100000 Platinum  according to an above range

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLr4h.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bReQx.png)

I set validate  values using ternary operator

```
@{
    var platinum = Model.ProgramID == 1 ? "block" : "none";
    var programType = Model.ProgramID == 1 ? "Platinum" : Model.ProgramID == 2 ? "Gold" : "Silver";
    var reducedlimit = Model.ReducedLimit == true ? "block" : "none";
    var min = Model.ProgramID == 1 ? 100000 : Model.ProgramID == 2 ? 50000 : 0;
    var max = Model.ProgramID == 1 ? 1000000000 : Model.ProgramID == 2 ? 99000 : 49000;
}
```

I want to do this here when any one select option in `RadioButtonFor` then the text box accept specific vales range in above.

this is `cshtml` file

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CoverageLimit, new { type = "number", min = @min, max = @max, @required = "required", @class = "form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 CoverageLimit" })
 @*<b class="programtype">min= @min  ,max=@max  , @programType </b>*@            
 </div>[here we are set min and max values using range ][1]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34639312/min-and-max-values-for-editorfor

Comment: I try this but it doesn't work

Comment: can i see your full cshtml source? and your model class.
and you want change min,max value when changed radiobutton checked?